# Four-velocity of a particle moving in a circle

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, vectors

If we have a particle moving in a circle then we will have $x$ and $y$ values of $$x = r\cos(\varphi)$$ $$y = r\sin(\varphi)$$As $ds = tv$ and $ds = \varphi r$ we can say that $$x = r\cos\bigg(\frac{tv}{r}\bigg)$$ $$y = r\sin\bigg(\frac{tv}{r}\bigg)$$ I am aware that the equation for four-velocity is $$\mathbf U = \frac{d\mathbf X}{d\tau}$$ however I am confused as to how to get a worldline for the particle to differentiate it. Can anyone help me out at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the particle moves on the curve $t \mapsto x^\mu (t)$, where $t$ is the time coordinate of the observer and

$$
x^\mu (t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 ct \\
r  \cos (\frac{vt}{r})\\
r  \sin (\frac{vt}{r})
\end{pmatrix}
\,.
$$
Now, you should calculate the proper time $\tau$ which is given by

$$
\tau = \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{c} \sqrt{-\eta(\dot{x},\dot{x})} dt' = \int_{0}^t \frac{dt'}{\gamma(t')} ,\quad \text{with} \quad \dot{x} \equiv \frac{d x}{dt'}\,.
$$
In this case $\gamma(t)=\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. So, the proper time is the usual one, namely

$$
\tau = \frac{1}{\gamma} t\,.
$$
All right! Now, you can calculate the four velocity:

$$
U^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{d\tau} = \gamma \frac{d x^\mu}{d t} = \gamma
\begin{pmatrix}
 c\\
-\beta \cos(\frac{vt}{r})\\
\beta \sin(\frac{vt}{r})
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$
where $\beta := \frac{v}{c}$.

Comment: @CooperCape You're welcome! But be aware of the fact that you cannot easily use the results of classical mechanics in SR. See for example the Ehrenfest's paradox.

Comment: Interestingly enough I've asked a question on that already!